# laravel 5.2 pass variable in all controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller

can someone help please, i want to make my varaibles global in all controllers without every time create instance.. settings = new Setting(); settings has only one row.

class Controller extends BaseController

```
protected $settings;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->settings = Setting::all();
        View::share('settings', $this->settings);
    }
}
```

and in another controller i use :

```
$this->settings->email;
```

but it does not work, please i search and see this method is not good, can someone please give me a good approach for this, laravel 5.2.

thanks so much..!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Providers for views. Use extended controller for controllers. Be sure your another controller extend controller which including global settings value. Be sure your another controller has not __construct or has construct with parent::__construct.

For example you can use 2 way:

```
class Controller extends BaseController{
    protected $settings;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->settings = Setting::all();
    }
}
```

then

```
class AnotherController extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
     //blahblah
    }
    public function anyMethod(){
        $asd = $this->settings;
    }
}
```

or

```
class AnotherController extends Controller{

    public function anyMethod(){
        $asd = $this->settings;
    }
}
```

If you want to use view files use AppServiceProvider.php in Providers

```
public function boot ()
{
    $settings = Setting::all();
    view ()->composer ( '*', function ( $view ) use ( $settings ) {
                $view->with ( 'settings', $settings );
            } );
}
```

Comment: Is this helps to you?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your add your settings variable to the parent controller.

App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public $settings;

    public function settings(){
       $this->settings = \App\Setting::all();
       return $this->settings;
    }
}
```

your app controllers extends controller you just need to add a contructor or call $this->settings() which will load your results to $this->settings in your controllers.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->settings();
    }

    public function someMethod(){
        // this is now available with results already loaded.
        $this->settings // option 1
        $this->settings() // this is the same as option 1 but runs the query when called and populates this settings property and returns the results.
    }
}
```